# pandas monthly frequency not being interpreted correctly

Tags: pandas

I am trying to do some calculation on the time offsets in pandas and something like this works:

```
pd.to_timedelta('1w')/'15min'
672.0
```

According to the docs, `M` is the monthly frequency and I do something like:

```
pd.to_timedelta('1M')/'15min'
0.06666666666666667
```

Looks like pandas is interpreting this as minutely frequency, rather than monthly?

Comment: I think I'm not seeing any 'month' in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html ... seems like minute is the only unit available for 'm' or 'M' ...where have you seen month ?

Comment: ahhhhh.... I was going by this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: mm.. I believe that must be a different 'time' type...but I guess it makes sense that 'timedelta' didn't want to deal with 'Months' as these are non 'deterministic' values